# Set Python version to be used in Jupyter Notebook for reproducability

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am using a Jupyter Notebook (in VSCode). I want to document which python version I am using with this notebook in order to be able to reproduce the same analysis at a later point. I always forget which Python version I use with a given Jupyter Notebook and when I come back to it after a long time I can't figure out which version I used at the time.

Is there a way to set the Python version at the beginning of the notebook?

I know that in order to manage module versions, we can install the specific version of a module in the following way:

```
!pip3 install allennlp==2.3
```

I use this code in the first cell in my notebook to document which module version is needed so that when I come back to the notebook or share it with other people, they can easily install the same module version. But what's the equivalent for the Python version that the notebook should use?

To be clear, I don't want to have to do anything manually outside of the Jupyter Notebook (e.g. open a separate terminal and execute some code or point-and-click to select the kernel in VSCode). I want to be able to send this notebook to a co-author and when they open it and execute the first cell it should select the Python version that I specified and install the correct package versions as in the example above.

Comment: I am afraid it's not available, you can't make sure your co-author has the same kernel. You can just annotate which version of the python you are using.

Comment: Wow, that's quite a blow to reproducible research. Is there a way to create a virtualenv from within the jupyter notebook? I.e. in the first cell use some code to create the virtualenv with the correct Python version, install all the necessary modules with the correct version numbers, and activate the virtualenv. And finally, in the last cell of the notebook deactivate the virtualenv?

Comment: I am afraid it's not feasible because you cannot even make sure your co-author has installed the Python version you are using.